# yii Active Record query

Tags: php, activerecord, join, yii

as written in Yii documentation we can use Active Record this way

```
$users=User::model()->with(array(
'posts'=>array(
    'select'=>false,
    'joinType'=>'INNER JOIN',
    'condition'=>'posts.published=1',
),
))->findAll();
```

I want to make some similar query but with posts of some category
if Post HAS_MANY Category

```
$users=User::model()->with(array(
'posts.categories'=>array(
    'select'=>false,
    'joinType'=>'INNER JOIN',
    //how should I write condition here?
    'condition'=>'posts.categories.id=1',
),
))->findAll();
```

Is it possible and what is the right syntax? I get 'unknown column posts.categories.id here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `on` instead of `condition`. Also the right `alias` is rather `categories` (depends on how you defined the relation in `posts`.

```
'on' => 'categories.id=1'
```